# Wrap a text within two lines in div

Tags: javascript, css

I wish to wrap a text with in only two lines inside div of especial width. If text goes beyond the length of two lines then i wish to show elipses.  is there any solution to do that using CSS?

I used css property `text-overflow:ellipsis`. its works only for one line. and also i used -`webkit-line-clamp:2`.which works well in chrome and safari browsers.
text wrap need to sopport in all the browsers(firefox and IE9).

Please suggest me the solution using css or javacsript?

Thanks in Advance.

One thing i observed..
if text fits in complete two lines its display like this.

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte 
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte ...
```

suppose if text fits half of the two lines like

```
 testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte 
    testtesttesttesttest                                                               ...
```

I am expecting like below:

```
 testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte 
 testtesttest...
```

I have tried with some modifications didn't succeeded.

Comment: http://reusablebits.com/post/2642059628/introducing-clamp-js

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with something like this

```
p.ellipsis {
position:relative;
line-height:1em;
max-height:2em;      /* 2 times the line-height to show 2 lines */
overflow: hidden;
}
p.ellipsis::after {
content:"...";
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
top:1em;
right:0;
padding:0 20px 1px 10px;
background: white;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7B9c/

Or you could use clamp.js

Edit:  To calculate if there is no overflow, you could do:

```
<p id="ellipsis">lots of text</p>

var $element = $('#ellipsis');
if( $element[0].offsetHeight < $element[0].scrollHeight || $element[0].offsetWidth < $element[0].scrollWidth){
   // your element have overflow
   $element.addClass('ellipsis');
}
else{
  $element.removeClass('ellipsis');
}
```

Then it will only show the dots if the element has stuff not shown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this working well. but problem is when resize the window then "..." will merge with text and also if the text contains only one line then these dots should be disappear.

Comment: made a few changes, added a fiddle so you can see that it works.  ... won't merge now, and dots dissapear if only one line

Comment: Thank you its perfect. Please check the above post. Need clarification on display the three dots.

Comment: I have tried with above function not able get the offsetheight and width. the value will be "undefined".Can you please add the jsfiddle for the above function( calculate if there is no overflow)